# MySQL JSON type insert and select using JDBC drivers

Tags: mysql, json

I am reading and writing mysql JSON type using JDBC driver and `ResultSet`. How do I fetch the JSON type from `ResultSet` as string JSON to be used in java program ?

```
mysql> set names UTF8MB4; // so that json values can be inserted using jdbc driver otherwise it was complaining of binary type
```

Java code (pseudo code):

```java
String myjsonString = "{x: y}"; // assume this is proper
conn.getPreparedStatement("insert into col_json values (myjsonString)");


rs = conn.getStatement("select col_json from table_json_test");

String myorig_json = rs.getString("col_json");
```

`myorig_json` is coming as a string like this:

```
"base64:type15:rO0ABXNyABdqYXZhLnV0aWwuTGlua2VkSGFzaE1hcDTATlwQbMD7AgABWgALYWNjZXNzT3JkZXJ4
cgARamF2YS51dGlsLkhhc2hNYXAFB9rBwxZg0QMAAkYACmxvYWRGYWN0b3JJAAl0aHJlc2hvbGR4
cD9AAAAAAAAMdwgAAAAQAAAAAXQABXJlZmlkdAAgZWI3ODkzZWVjMDU5NGNhMjlhYjY1OTJjMjFj
MjIwNWZ4AA=="
```

expected is `"{x: y}"`

Answer (score 3):

The JSON data type in MySQL is a special type that's stored internally as a binary object. This is why you can't get the value from the database as a string - the JDBC driver will grab the contents of the binary value and try to read it as a `String`, giving you the garbage you see.

JDBC drivers don't support the JSON object type at all. Instead, you have two options:

1. Store your JSON in a `TEXT` field - then you can use `getString` to read it, but you'll have to parse it yourself.
2. Use MySQL's special JSON query language to build your queries, which will mean that your `ResultSet` contains data read from the JSON and converted for you. For example, having the query:

```sql
SELECT col_json->>'$.x' AS x FROM <table>
```

will give you a `ResultSet` containing:

```
+----+
|  x |
+----+
|  y |
+----+
```

and you can use `resultSet.getString(1)` to extract the value.

There are plenty of tutorials around for how to query JSON fields in MySQL. Here's a nice simple one to start you off: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-json/